# Fibonacci Recursion in Java - No For Loops?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, recursion, fibonacci

I don't understand what I should be doing. My professor wants us to create a Fibonacci sequence using recursion. No for loops are allowed, and I (being an amateur) don't know how to create a String of say, 6 numbers in sequence.

Here are his directions: *"Using recursion, create a method that returns a String containing a Fibonacci sequence.  Take in an integer to determine how many values of the sequence you should return."*

This is what I have thus far...

```
import java.util.*;

public class fibo {

  public final static int n = 0;
  public static String s = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please put in a number.");

    int n = scn.nextInt();

    s = Integer.toString(n);

    System.out.println(n+ ": " + fibonacci(n));
  }

  public static int fibonacci(int n) {  

    if(n <= 1)
      return n;

    else       
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }
}
```

In addition to that, I feel like a lot of it is really inefficient and messy. Can someone really explain and help me with what I should be doing?

Comment: It looks like it's probably doing what you've been asked. I suspect efficiency may come later. It's not how I'd handle negative values, admittedly...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are generating the nth number in the Fibonacci sequence, it seems to me, you need to store all the values you are generating (not just the last one) and display them.

So rather than just `f(n)`, you need to display `f(1), f(2), ..., f(n-1), f(n)` once you have done that you have completed your assignment.

Comment: Not only that, but creating the sequence should be contained inside the recursive function. It would be possible to do it as a separate, also recursive, function in order to sidestep the "no loops" requirement, and that would certainly be easier, as bundling it into one function would leave you with a a lot of messy state being passed in the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine:

```
public class Fibonacci {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Fib(3));

  }

  // returns the next number in the Fibonacci sequence
  public static int Fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
      return n;
    } else {
      return Fib(n - 1) + Fib(n - 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code which works good, without unnecessary Code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Fibonaccis {



  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Lägg in ett nummer.");

    int n = scn.nextInt();



    System.out.println(n+ ": " + fibonacci(n));
  }

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  public static int fibonacci(int n) {  

    if(n <= 1)
      return n;

    else       
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code showing Fibonacci till 8 without any loop...

```
public class FinnonnacciDemo2 {

    static int no = 0, n = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This will print series till 8
        fib(0, 1);
    }

    public static void fib(int a, int b) {
        // Terminating condition.
        if (a >= n) {
            return;
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("\t" + no);
            no = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = no;
            fib(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```